# Wordpress add_filter(the_content,'func') not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress

I use `add_filter(the_content,'func')` to add [some words] into contents.

When `the_content()` run , [some words] were not shown in content.

However, if `echo` or `vad_dump` something before calling `the_content()`, [some words] would be shown.

```
 func($content) {
    return $content.'[some words]';
}
```

Comment: Seems the problem is not in this piece of code. You probably don't modify it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_filter('the_content','func');

function func(){
  return $content.'[some words]';
}
```

You forgot to add `'` at the starting and ending of `the_content`.